# JSP - Forward an attribute that has already been forwarded to another page

Tags: jsp

On page 1: 
I forward the following:

```
<form action="purchase.jsp" method="GET">
          <input type = "hidden" name = "item_name" 
                 value = "${result.rows[0]['item_name']}" /> 
          <input type = "hidden" name = "item_code" 
                 value = "${result.rows[0]['item_code']}" />    
          <input type = "hidden" name = "item_price" 
                 value = "${result.rows[0]['item_price']}" /> 
          <input type = "submit" id="buy" value = "Buy" />
        </form>
```

It then is received on the second page, and it shows up fine when i request the attrbute.

```
<%= request.getParameter( "item_name" ) %> (<%= request.getParameter( "item_code" ) %>) with a price of &pound;
<%= request.getParameter( "item_price" ) %> </h2>
```

Now this parameter shows up on this page, but I want to use this parameter on another page, but first i POST it with a form:

```
<form action="complete_purchase.jsp" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="Complete Purchase" />
  <input type = "hidden" name = "item_price" value = "${request.setAttribute(item_price)}" /> 
</form>
```

And now i want to retrieve it on the last page but it shows up as NULL

```
You have bought: <%= request.getParameter( "item_name" ) %> (<%= request.getParameter( "item_code" ) %>) 
<br />
Total: &pound; <%= request.getParameter( "item_price") %>
```

What am i doing wrong that it wont show this parameter from the 2nd page onto the 3rd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with second form, you use `setAttribute` instead of `getParameter`:

```
<form action="complete_purchase.jsp" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="Complete Purchase" />
  <input type = "hidden" name = "item_price" value = "<%= request.getParameter( "item_price" ) %>" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Hmm although it isn't returning NULL, its returning blank items, like nothing is appearing.

Comment: I'll try this. Also should my method be POST or GET?

Comment: It worked, Perfect thank you very much, I did try that once but formatted it incorrectly.